# problem with switch

Tags: php, switch-statement

Here is the sample code.

```
<?php
$a =2;
switch($a) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        echo "Logic for error validations";

    case 1:
        echo "1. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 2:
        echo "2. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 3:
        echo "3. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 4:
        echo "4. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 5:
        echo "5. code to be executed";
        break;
}
?>
```

For the value of `$a` as `1,2,3` i have same error validations to do.. The update logic differs again for each value of $a.

Inorder to acheive the above said logic, i used case 1: case 2: case 3:and did not use BREAK intentionally. so that it will continue executing.

But it results in o/p, 
*Logic for error validations 1. code to be executed*.

Now the output expected is, *Logic for error validations 2. code to be executed*.

Please help me or suggest changes to produce the expected output. I can use IF and based on the value of $a, change the code. But i am trying to do with the help of switch, which can be expandable for a ranging values of $a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have duplicate case values. You would have to do something like below.

```
<?php
$a =2;
switch($a) {
    case 1:
        error();
        echo "1. code to be executed";
        break;
    case 2:
        error();
        echo "2. code to be executed";
        break;
    case 3:
        error();
        echo "3. code to be executed";
        break;
    case 4:
        echo "4. code to be executed";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo "5. code to be executed";
        break;
}

function error()
{
    echo "Logic for error validations";
}


?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Can't use the same value in `case` twice.

```
<?php
$a =2;
switch($a) {
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
    echo "Logic for error validations";
}
switch($a) {
case 1:
    echo "1. code to be executed";
    break;
case 2:
    echo "2. code to be executed";
    break;
case 3:
    echo "3. code to be executed";
    break;
case 4:
    echo "4. code to be executed";
    break;
case 5:
    echo "5. code to be executed";
    break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Split it into two switches. It is usually a bad Idea to have the same label twice in a switch

```
switch($a) {

    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        echo "Logic for error validations";
}

switch($a){
    case 1:
        echo "1. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 2:
        echo "2. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 3:
        echo "3. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 4:
        echo "4. code to be executed";
        break;

    case 5:
        echo "5. code to be executed";
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

try with doing a second switch

```
<?php
$a =2;
switch($a) {

    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:

        echo "Logic for error validations";
        switch($a){
            case 1:
            echo "1. code to be executed";
            break;
        }

     break;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using 2 case statements for this, the first containing the error validations and the second processing the results.